# .then() function is called before main function gets completed - Q.nfcall

Tags: node.js, promise, q

A() function return promises after `1000` ms and throws an error. So, the next execution should be into `catch`. But, `.then()` function gets executed even after the main function throws an error.

#### Test.js

```
var Test1 = require("./Test1.js")
var Q = require('q');
var value = "Hardik";
var value1 = "Shah";

A()
  .then(Test1.B(value, value1))
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log("In catch: ", e.message);
  });


  function A(){
    console.log("In A function");
    return Q.nfcall(AInner);
  }

  function AInner(callback){
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback({message: "Error from A Inner"});
    }, 1000)
  }
```

#### Test1.js

```
'use strict';

var Q = require("q");

module.exports = {B:B}

function B(value, value1){
  console.log("In B function: ", value, " ", value1);
  return Q.nfcall(BInner);
}

function BInner(callback){
  console.log("In BInner function");
  callback({message: "Error from BInner"});
}
```

**Actual Output:**

> ```
> In A function
> In B function:  Hardik   Shah
> In BInner function
> In catch: Error from A Inner
> ```

**Expected Output:**

> ```
> In A function
> Error from A Inner // After 1000 ms
> ```

---

#### I have solved issue by modifying below code: Works perfect

```
A()
  .then(function(){
    return Test1.B(value, value1)
  }).then(function(data){
     console.log("final data", data);
  })
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log(e.message);
  });
```

But, what is wrong with the above code?

Please give me a good explanation with the correct way to write code in the sequence of `then` rather than under `then`.

You can try here https://repl.it/@hrdk108/Hardik-Shah-Issue1 to reproduce an issue.

Comment: because `AInner` is not returning a promise?, it returned `undefined` which the chains accepts a valid value to continue the chain. I might be wrong.

Comment: @kiddorails AInner returns `callback function` and I have handled that returned `callback function` to convert into promise using `Q.nfcall`. This is not an issue because if so then it will throw an error without completing execution.

Comment: figured it. change to `.then(() => Test1.B(value, value1))`, you are invoking `Test1.B` rather than giving a callback.

Comment: What do you mean by "*write code in the sequence of then rather than under then.*"?

Comment: @Bergi I mean I want to write code something like this `A.then(B).then(C).catch(function(e){})` where `A,B and C` are function.

Comment: @HardikShah Well yes, `B` and `C` need to be functions for that. The `Test1.B(value, value1)` value that you passed in your original code is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long brainstorm, I have figured out and it is just a silly mistake.

- That Mistake is just because I invoked `Test1.B()` while defining
  into `then`. Which is already answered in the above answer. So, One solution is I have already mentioned in the question.

---

### Second solution:

---

The correct way to write a `then` sequence is:

**`Test1.B` function without arguments:**

---

```
A()
  .then(Test1.B)
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log("In catch: ", e.message);
  });
```

**`Test1.B` with arguments:** use `bind`

```
A()
  .then(Test1.B.bind(null, value, value1))
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log("In catch: ", e.message);
  });
```

Check here corrected example https://repl.it/@hrdk108/Hardik-Shah-Issue1

---

**For Just FYI,**

Actually, When you are using `Q.nfcall` you should take care of passing arguments design.

> - **nfcall** expects arguments provided individually
>
> For Example:
>
> ```
> Q.nfcall(B, value, value1);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is, you are invoking `Test1.B(value, value1)` inside `then`, rather than keeping it as callback. Because, once you used it as invocation, it started it's own promise chain. To fix it, change it to:

```
var Test1 = require("./Test1.js")
var Q = require('q');
var value = "Hardik";
var value1 = "Shah";

A()
  .then(function() { Test1.B(value, value1) }) // note here
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log("In catch: ", e.message);
  });


  function A(){
    console.log("In A function");
    return Q.nfcall(AInner);
  }

  function AInner(callback){
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback({message: "Error from A Inner"});
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Comment: this solution I have already mentioned in the question under `I have solved issue by modifying below code: Works perfect` section already.

Comment: argh. I didn't see that section. But bottom line is, you do realize that *why* your first version is not working now, right? You have to give the function to invoke to `then`, rather than invoking it